# Script to move email addresses from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have problems figuring out how to script the following:

```
1. I have a sheet tab_A:
Col_A, Col_B
URL_1, Email_1
URL_2, Email_2
URL_3, Email_3

1. I have a sheet tab_B:
Col_A, ..., Col_F
URL_3, empty
URL_1, empty
URL_2, empty
```

"..." means several columns with data.

I need a script that takes row for row in tab_A, copy the email address, find the correct row in tab_B (the same URL) and paste the email in Col F.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy the values of the column "B" of "tab_A" to the column "F" of "tab_B" by checking the column "A" of "tab_A" and "tab_B" on the Spreadsheet.
- For example, when the row 1 has `URL_1, Email_1` on "tab_A" and the row 2 has `URL_1` on "tab_B", you want to copy the value of `Email_1` to the column "F" of "tab_B" with the same row.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve values from "tab_A" and create an object for searching the value of the column "A".
2. Create an array for putting values to "tab_B".
3. Put the values to "tab_B".

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and run `myFunction`. By this, the values are put to "tab_B". Before you use this, please set the sheet names for your actual situation.

```
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve values from "tab_A" and create an object for searching the value of the column "A".
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const tabA = ss.getSheetByName("tab_A");
  const sourceValues = tabA.getDataRange().getValues();
  const obj = sourceValues.reduce((o, [a, b]) => Object.assign(o, {[a]: b}), {});

  // 2. Create an array for putting values to "tab_B".
  const tabB = ss.getSheetByName("tab_B");
  const outputValues = tabB.getDataRange().getValues().map(r => [obj[r[0]] || ""]);

  // 3. Put the values to "tab_B".
  tabB.getRange(1, 6, outputValues.length, 1).setValues(outputValues);
}
```

#### Note:

- When you want to use above script as the custom function, you can also use the following script. In this case, please put a custom formula of `=SAMPLE(tab_A!A1:B, tab_B!A1:A)` to the cell "F1" of "tab_B".

  ```
    function SAMPLE(valuesOfTabA, valuesOfTabB) {
      const obj = valuesOfTabA.reduce((o, [a, b]) => Object.assign(o, {[a]: b}), {});
      return valuesOfTabB.map(r => [obj[r[0]] || ""]);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @Snookie Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.